# Ошибки в json коде в настройках vs code

Tags: javascript, json, веб-программирование, visual-studio-code

Имеется файл [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в нем три ошибки, если я их убираю перестаёт работать autoprefixer, как бы убрать ошибки, и что бы автопрефиксер  работал.

```
{
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    },
    {
    "autoprefixer.browsers": [
        "last 2 versions",
        "> 1%"
        ]
    }


}
```

Comment: Будьте добры, добавьте код текстом.

Comment: На скриншоте явно невалидный JSON